# d3 SVG translate and scale one group but only translate the other

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm building an activity map using d3. I display a world map and then some dots who represent activity.
The map should be both panable and zoomable.

the function I use to transform at the moment looks like this:

```
function move() {

    var t = d3.event.translate;
    var s = d3.event.scale;
    var h = height / 4;


    t[ 0 ] = Math.min(
        ( width / height ) * ( s - 1 ),
        Math.max( width * ( 1 - s ), t[ 0 ] )
    );

    t[ 1 ] = Math.min(
        h * ( s - 1 ) + h * s,
        Math.max( height * ( 1 - s ) - h * s, t[ 1 ] )
    );

    zoom.translate( t );
    ctrl.g.attr( 'transform', 'translate(' + t + ')scale(' + s + ')' );
    ctrl.points.attr( 'transform', 'translate(' + t + ')' );

    //adjust the country hover stroke width based on zoom level
    d3.selectAll( '.country' ).style( 'stroke-width', 1.5 / s );

}
```

This results in the dots moving around in stead of maintaining their position based on latitude and longitude. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:
I forgot to mention that the dots should maintain their scale, that is to say even though I've zoomed in on the world map the dots should not scale, only move.

Answer (score 0):

I have found my solution,

I had forgotten to scale down the points :/

I added

```
d3.selectAll( '.point' ).attr('r', 5/s);
```

to scale the points with the rest of the map.